# Value deep in dicts

Tags: ansible

Is there an easy way get access a value inside of nested dicts that doesn't error if one of the dicts exists. Not sure what to call it, but it is proposed as [optional chaining for ECMAScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining). I the only thing I have found was a [closed PR](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/11083) for adding "safe_item", but it was closed.

I am trying to set do something like `"{{ hostvars[item].ip_addr | default(hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']) }}"`, but have it not error when the `ansible_default_ipv4` has not been set (eg when one of the hosts is down).

Something like `"{{ hostvars[item].ip_addr | default(hostvars[item] | getattr(['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address'], omit)) }}"` would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit ugly but you can nest `default` filters:

```
{{ hostvars[item].ip_addr | default(hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] | default(omit)) }}
```

Note that `omit` will only work when providing non required values to a module parameter. In other cases (e.g. setting a var value with `set_fact`), you will have to provide some default value.